# docker file creation for nginx not working

Tags: docker

I'm trying to build a docker file using nginx Web Server, but getting error while building docker image. Any help is greatly appreciated.

[image: web server file]

[image: error]

Comment: Why the photos of your screen and not screenshots?

Comment: Avoid asking questions with images !  You have just a couple lines to write ...

Comment: It's very easy and more clean to copy the content of your terminal and then have nice question presentation, why this annoying screen images in the question ?

Answer (score 0):

This mostly happens when you have not updated your source list. Try running `apt-get update` before installing nginx package.

Your Dockerfile should look like this

```
FROM ubuntu
MAINTAINER Pradeep
RUN apt-get update
RUN apt-get install -y nginx
RUN apt-get clean
EXPOSE 80
CMD ["nginx", "-D", "FOREGROUND"]
```

Either way if you are looking to use nginx i would recommend you use [nginx official docker image](https://hub.docker.com/_/nginx/)

Comment: Thanks Thomas. That really helped!!. and i'm using the offical docker image for nginx